# CAST nvarchar to datetime regardless of login date format?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, casting, nvarchar

I've got 2 servers with two different login date formats (`English` & `British English`).

I need to be able to `CAST` an nvarchar value to datetime regardless of the date format.

I have the following query:

```
select cast('2011-13-07' as datetime)
```

This works on 1 server, but not the other.

Is there another way I can represent `13/7/2011` as a `datetime` object for both servers?

For consistency, the query needs to be identical on both servers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the ISO-8601 standard format `YYYYMMDD`:

```
SELECT CAST('20110713' as DATETIME)
```

Don't use any dashes! That format will work *on any SQL Server instance*, regardless of language, regional, locale settings - **it just works**!

The other format in ISO-8601 is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` - this one includes dashes, but also a time portion.

Comment: I get error `The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.`

Comment: @Curt: yeah - sorry - I had the day and month mixed up at first. You need year, month, day (`20110713`)